# Set MS Office language programmatically (VBA/VB/API)

Tags: vba, winapi, vb6, ms-office

MS office programs have various document and app-specific language settings.  This isn't about those.  This is about the language settings you access via the Microsoft Office 2010 Language Preferences program or through the in-app dialogs that call up the same dialog (Review | Language | Language Preferences in Word/PPT for example).

I'm looking for a way to access this same functionality but under program control.

Why?  Because when you use the MS-supplied dialog to change language, MS thoughtfully blows away all of your Outlook and Word customizations (renames your Normal.dotm and NormalEmail.dotm files to Normal.dotm.old and NormalEmail.dotm.old, but doesn't seem able to restore them when you change back to the original language).

Result:  Change languages and you lose your QuickParts and possibly other stuff.  That's not acceptable.

If I could control the language setting via my own tool, I figure it'd be child's play to first save the existing customizations to e.g. Normal.dotm.1033 if I'm currently set to English (US) and if I later change the language back to English (US) to copy that file back to Normal.dotm, thus restoring my US English customizations.

Comment: Surely the Office program behavior was based on the assumption that the user doesn't change his native language on a daily basis.  Also the reason that the Application.Language property only has a getter and not a setter.  That blows a hole in your plan.  You can still backup files of course.

Comment: I see nothing here that has anything to do with VB6, nor to do with programming at all.  Looks like an end user usage question.

Comment: Bob77:  "but under program control"  IOW, programmatically.  Hans: Office's behavior seems based on the assumption that one will never change the language setting, or that one doesn't mind having all of one's customizations trashed when one does.  This seems an unreasonable assumption to me.  The UI provides the user a way to change the default language.  Why shouldn't it be exposed to code?

Comment: Interesting question. One path I followed and ruled out is that the Language option menu isn't exposed under Excel by xlDialogs - although the `Advanced` and `General` options are

Answer (score 1):

I think I've found it.  For Office 2010:

HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Office\14.0\Common\LanguageResources

InstallLanguage DWORD
Set its value to LangID

When you change default languages using the Office language tool or the dialog in Office apps as able, that's what changes in the reg.  It also changes this to the LangID of whatever the previous default language was:

PreviousInstallLanguage